# How to delete node on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I try to delete node on agens graph and failed.

```
lee=# match (n:v{id:1}) delete n;
ERROR:  vertex 4 in "v" has edge(s)
```

How to delete node?

Answer (score 0):

Add detach before delete token.

```
assam=# match (n:v{id:1}) detach delete n;
GRAPH WRITE (DELETE VERTEX 1, DELETE EDGE 1)
```